# Two promises with a single then for either one of them

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I have a function that takes an input, according to that input it will either call one of two functions (both return a promise) I want then to call the same `.then()` after whatever of them happened.

I found `Promise.any()` but that doesn't quite do what I want.

**For curious minds :**

I am working on a `react-native` app and want to either open the camera or the gallery then handle the photo in a `then()`.

How can I do that?

Comment: `Promise.finally()`

Comment: FYI, it's a good idea to just ask "how can I do this" instead of "what's the best way to do this" because the former is answerable, whereas the latter asks for opinions. Generally, if you ask "how", no one's going to answer with the worst way of doing things :).

Comment: It would also be nice to see what you've tried and how your functions are arranged so that we can give you advice that works for your scenario.

Comment: Is this just one of those situations where you've overlooked that promises can be stored in variables?  `foo().then(next)` can be `let p = foo(); p.then(next);`  Which also means it can be `let p = maybe ? foo() : bar(); p.then(next);`

Comment: @Wyck, I think you are right, I just tried it but wasn't sure that's a "good way" of achieving this.

Comment: @HereticMonkey, you are totally right, I am sorry :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function myFunction(input) {
  const promise = input === X ? callOne() : callTwo();
  return promise.then(handleEitherFunction);
}
```

Comment: That actually what worked for me, so easy, thank you

Answer (score 1):

I may be missing something, but I believe you can just fulfill with your promise:

```js
new Promise(fulfill => {
    if( ... someCondition ...){
        fulfill(selectPhoto());
    }
    else {
        fulfill(pickPhoto());
    }
}).then(selectedPhoto => {
    console.log(selectedPhoto);
});
```

The functions `selectPhoto` and `pickPhoto` both return promises. The promise will chain and the `console.log` function will only be called once the promise passed to fulfill is fulfilled.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the resolve function of the containing Promise, and call it on any of the promises inside like so.

```
const OneForTwo = new Promise( (resolve,reject) => {
    const openCamera = new Promise(() => { console.log('your camera code') }).then( resolve )
    const openGallery = new Promise(() => { console.log('your gallery code') }).then( resolve )
}).then( value => console.log('i got resolved by any of those promises'))
```

I dont know how you resolve your promises but you get the idea, as soon as any of those 2 promises resolve, they will call the "resolve" of the container, which will trigger the "then".

hope this what you looking for.